# ibus not working in wayland Gnome shell 3.26 in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ibus, gnome-shell, wayland

Although ibus-daemon is shown as enabled and active, there is no input icon appear in the top panel. Neither SUPER+SPACE to toggle language selection. I'm on Xwayland session. I tried restarting and it did not work. ibus configuration setup etc showed correctly.

Comment: When you start the ibus configuration application, does it display any sort of notification dialog?

Comment: ibus-daemon is running, I cannot restart it, as keyboard stops working. No notifications.  If you are asking about ibus-setup, it worked fine. But, in dmesg I saw segmentation fault error:                                                                                                               ibus-setup-m17n[8449]: segfault at 60 ip 000055ba199a0877 sp 00007fff559bb410 error 4 in ibus-setup-m17n[55ba1999d000+6000]
[11422.076468] ibus-setup-m17n[8460]: segfault at 60 ip 0000559c4e815877 sp 00007ffc043b1ab0 error 4 in ibus-setup-m17n[559c4e812000+6000]

Comment: Are you able to use the keyboard after logging in?

Comment: @OmariCelestine : Yes, I can use keyboard. Just that, if I try to restart ibus-daemon from a terminal it ends up with keyboard not working.

Comment: Do you have the *im-config* (input manager) package installed? If not, could you run the command *sudo apt-get install im-config* in the terminal to install it?

Comment: im-config is configured for ibus. It's already installed.

Comment: I was having a similar situation to yours and the only solution I found was to switch the input method from *ibus* to *xim* which uses the build in language configuration.

Comment: I will try now. But. since this is wayland session (wayland on X),..Let's check out.

Comment: It should still work. By the way, why don't you use the xorg session?

Comment: No, it did not work. Yes, I feel slightly faster with wayland session and is testing out wayland (which is almost OK, except for quirks like this). BTW, I noticed this error in dmesg after a restart: [   77.136259] traps: ibus-ui-gtk3[1565] general protection ip:7fd4204dd253 sp:7ffd74de90b0 error:0 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7fd420440000+134000]

Comment: You restarted after changing the input method? Open the Language Support settings application and ensure that the selected input method is now *XIM*.

Comment: Yes. restarted, but seems to be not working. I tried restarting ibus-daemon and checked /var/log/syslong and this is what it says: gnome-terminal-[1534]: Loading IM context type 'xim' failed
Dec 11 05:37:45 HP-LAPTOP-15 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1223]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.

Comment: Also confirm that ibus is not running on Gnome shell in Xorg session too. :/ . I'm wondering, if the old input method - scim, will work or not?

Comment: Could you tell me if you have any of the following packages installed *uim-\**, *ibus-wayland*, *ibus-gtk3*?

Comment: no packages with uim-*. But,  ibus-wayland, ibus-gtk3 are installed.

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue with ibus. Could you trying installing the following packages: *uim-xim*, *uim-utils*, *libuim8*, *uim-common* then enable the *XIM* input method and restart. Let me know of the results.

Comment: I tried with uim-xim and the result is the same. No iBus input. From searching, it turns out to be a problem with wayland.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1727174